# Not another challenge!

Tags: riddle, video-games

I have created a new riddle: this one about Video games! Well, here you go!

> *From a land of monsters, an embarrassed boy*
>
> *Lurks through a bush and inhales a tomato!*
>
> *"Urrrgh!" Says he, after being transformed*
>
> *For now he patch up a world with castles! He*
>
> *Fares well with his quest, and stitches up the world!*

The answer should be the name of the game.

Comment: What is the answer supposed to be here?

Comment: I think it is "what is the video game"

Comment: @Zimonze what Duck said sorry for not clairifing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it

> Kirby's Epic Yarn?

From a land of monsters, an embarrassed boy

> Kirby's world is full of monsters

Lurks through a bush and inhales a tomato!

> The game starts with Kirby eating a cursed tomato.

"Urrrgh!" Says he, after being transformed

> Kirby transforms his body to have new powers

For now he patch up a world with castles! He

> Kirby collects patches to unlock new levels, and the first level is Patch Castle.

Fares well with his quest, and stitches up the world!

> Kirby must collect the magic yarn to stitch the world together.

Also,

> The first letter of each line spells FLUFF.

Comment: Congrats! Good job on finding the secret Prince Fluff clue!

Comment: @Yout Ried I was wondering why "He" was on the fourth line and not the fifth.

Answer (score 1):

Is the video game:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wonder_Boy_in_Monster_Land

About a boy in monster land

Comment: Not quite. There are a lot of hints throughout the riddle.